# Store and analyize logs data from diffenrent application

Tags: azure, elastic, storage, logstash

We have different applications that generate logs intensively, We do a lot of analytics, visualizations, monitoring on these logs.

Currently, we are using azure app insights to do the visualization but it's not enough for the advanced visualization we need, so we decided to move the data to another database that it's suitable for analyzing the data and be able to connect with tableau.

Initially, we are exploring elasticsearch but there is no straight forward connector to tableau so we need to build our connector and also I found some more options like ClickHouse, PrestoDB, InfluxDB, Apache HBase and Tarantool

So my question is, what is the best practice a storage system for logs data which hot active, continuous analysis, ability to monitor and could integrate with tableau?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use Kibana with Elasticsearch or does that not give you the 'advanced' features you need?

Have you looked at this connector for ES and Tableau? https://www.dremio.com/tutorials/unlocking-tableau-on-elasticsearch/